# I am getting error on site bulit in yii and error is Fatal error Out of memory

Tags: php, yii, memory-leaks

I am getting an error on site built in yii and error is:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 6815744) (tried to allocate 122880 bytes)
```

How to resolve this on server?

Comment: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 786432) (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/live/newsite/common/lib/Yii/YiiBase.php on line 417

Comment: When are you getting this? Every request? A specific request? What code is executing before this error? A large query? A loop?

Comment: i was getting this on every request but the issue resolved after restarting my server and there are different type of queries on every page